# HTML and JavaScript form for converting units

Tags: javascript, function, validation, html

I'm trying to make form, using HTML and JavaScript and using dropdown list. So I have searched over and over, I found similar problems, but coun't resolve anything from the answers. So, I want my form to be selected via Dropdown menu, so I can get like "Kilometers" and convert them to "Miles" or "Feet", depends on what I chose. I got it working for the Temparature form, but only for convertion from Celsius to Farenhait, to other way around does not work and I don't know why. Here is HTML code:

```
<body onload="startTime()">
    <p>Temparature</p>
    <br />
    <form>
        <input id="c" name="c" onkeyup="preveri()">
        <select id="chose1">
            <option></option>
            <option value="C">Celzija</option>
            <option value="F">Farenhait</option>
        </select>
        <br />equals
        <br />
        <input id="f" name="f" onkeyup="preveri()">
        <select id="chose2">
            <option></option>
            <option value="C">Celzija</option>
            <option value="F">Farenhait</option>
        </select>
    </form>
    <br />
    <p>Lenght</p>
    <form>
        <input id="k" name="k" onkeyup="preveri1()">
        <select id="chose2">
            <option></option>
            <option value="K">Kilometer</option>
            <option value="M">Miles</option>
        </select>
        <br />equals
        <br />
        <input id="m" name="m" onkeyup="preveri1()">
        <select id="chose2">
            <option></option>
            <option value="K">Kilometer</option>
            <option value="M">Miles</option>
        </select>
    </form>


    <option value="K">Kilometer</option>
    <option value="M">Miles</option>
    <div id="txt"></div>
</body>
```

and here is JavaScript code:

```
function preveri(neke)
{
    neke=document.getElementById("chose1").value;
    if(neke=="C")
    {
        fahr=document.getElementById("c").value * 9 / 5 + 32;
        document.getElementById("f").value=Math.round(fahr);
    }else   
    {
        cels=(document.getElementById("f").value -32) * 5 / 9;
        document.getElementById("c").value=Math.round(cels);
    }
}

function preveri1(neke1)
{
    neke1=document.getElementById("chose2").value;
    if(neke1=="K")
    {
        kilo=document.getElementById("k").value * 0.621371;
        document.getElementById("m").value=Math.round(kilo);
    }else   
    {
        mile=(document.getElementById("m").value) / 0.621371;
        document.getElementById("k").value=Math.round(mile);
    }
}
function startTime()
{
    var today=new Date();
    var h=today.getHours();
    var m=today.getMinutes();
    var s=today.getSeconds();
// doda 0 pred  števila<10
    m=checkTime(m);
    s=checkTime(s);
    document.getElementById('txt').innerHTML=h+":"+m+":"+s;
    t=setTimeout('startTime()',500);
}
function checkTime(i)
{
if (i<10)
{
    i="0" + i;
}
    return i;
}
```

Something is wrong, I don't know what, if you could be kind enough to help me, I'm a beginger in JavaScript.

Comment: You have a few things that are wrong in your code. For starters, you are calling preveri(), but the function signature is preveri(neke). Why are you using 2 forms?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've updated your code and now are only 2 text-fields and lots of different units to choose from in the drop-down boxes. Also there are different options depending on the *#chose1* drop-down box value. I've also added some input validation, now a number is required in the text-box. Anyway, here's the new code:

HTML

```
<h1>What do you want to convert?</h1>
<input id="c" name="c" onkeyup="preveri()" onkeydown="validate(event)"> <!-- New function to make sure user enters a number -->
<select id="chose1" >
<option></option>
<option value="C">Celsius</option>
<option value="F">Farenhait</option>
<option value="KM">Kilometers</option>
</select><br />
equals<br />
<input id="f" name="f" disabled>
<select id="chose2">
<option></option>
</select> 
<div id="txt"></div>
```

Javascript

```
    $( "#chose1" ).change(function(){ // When the value of #chose1 changes
    var choseval = $("#chose1").val(); // Get value of #chose1
    if(choseval == "C"){
        changeoption("#chose2", ["Farenhait", "Kelvin"], ["F1", "K1"]); // New custom function, changeoption(element, options [must be a list], values [must be a list]
    }
    if(choseval == "F"){
    changeoption("#chose2", ["Celsius", "Kelvin"], ["C2", "K2"]);
    }
    if(choseval == "KM"){
    changeoption("#chose2", ["Miles", "Feet"], ["M1", "Fe1"]);
    }
});

function changeoption(element, options, values){
    $(element).empty(); //Clear options
    var i = 0;
    while(i<options.length){ //Moves selected term in list
    $(element).append($("<option>").val(values[i]).html(options[i])); // Add our option and values
    i++; // Move onto next list item
    }} 

function preveri()
{
    var convert=document.getElementById("chose2").value; // What do we want to convert to? This works because there's only one possible value for each unit of measurement

    if(convert=="F1"){ // Farenhait for celsius
        cels=Number(document.getElementById("c").value *1.8) + 32;
        document.getElementById("f").value=Math.round(cels);
    }
    if(convert=="K1"){ // Kelvin for celsius
        cels=Number(document.getElementById("c").value) + 273.15;
        document.getElementById("f").value=Math.round(cels);
    }
    if(convert=="C2"){ // Celsius for farenhait
        cels=Number(document.getElementById("c").value - 32) * (5/9);
        document.getElementById("f").value=Math.round(cels);
    }
    if(convert=="K2"){ // Kelvin for farenhait
        cels=Number(document.getElementById("c").value - 32) * (5/9) + 273.15;
        document.getElementById("f").value=Math.round(cels);
    }
    if(convert=="M1"){ // Miles for kilometer
        cels=Number(document.getElementById("c").value) * 0.62137;
        document.getElementById("f").value=Math.round(cels);
    }
    if(convert=="Fe1"){ // Feet for kilometer
        cels=Number(document.getElementById("c").value) * 3280.8399;
        document.getElementById("f").value=Math.round(cels);
    }
}

function validate(e){ // Our validate function
    x = e.keyCode;
    if((x<60&&x>47)||x==8||(x<106&&x>95)||x==110||x==190||x==16||x==17||x==18){ // Ignore numbers and other important keys, such as SHIFT and CONTROL
        return;
    }
    else{window.setTimeout("remove()",1);} // Trigger remove
}

function remove(){ // Remove invalid character
    y = document.getElementsByName("c")[0];
    q = y.value;
    q = q.slice(0, - 1); // Remove end character from value
    y.value = q;
}

function checkTime(i)
{
if (i<10)
{
    i="0" + i;
}
    return i;
}

function startTime(){
    var today=new Date();
    var h=today.getHours();
    var m=today.getMinutes();
    var s=today.getSeconds();
    // doda 0 pred  števila<10
    m=checkTime(m);
    s=checkTime(s);
    document.getElementById('txt').innerHTML=h+":"+m+":"+s;
    t=setTimeout('startTime()',500);
    }

$("docuemnt").ready(function(){ // I've moved your starttime function as I couldn't get it to work in JSFiddle with it being in the onload body tag attribute
    startTime();
});
```

CSS - to style disabled text-box:

```
#f{
    -webkit-appearance: textfield;
    background-color: white;
    border: 2px inset;
    color: black;
}
```

I've used some JQuery, so now you'll have to import it, here's the HTML - it's important to import this ***before*** your script otherwise the JQuery functions won't work:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
```

**Here's a JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/HZfYL/2/**

If you need any more help, don't hesitate to leave a comment

Comment: Thanks for the replay, but I think there is something not working quite right, as I'm able to choose from what I'm going to convert, but not into what I'm going to convert... I think it has something to do with jquery ...

Comment: on JSFiddle it's working fine, but once I put it in the actual file (using dreamweaver), It's not working correctly. I can choose to convert from "Kilometers", but I can't choose to convert it into "feet" or "miles" like on JSFiddle. I don't know what is wrong, I did everything as you said, I imported JQuery HTML code before my JavaScript code. Still not working :s ... Really confused right now.

Comment: Could you send us a link to your HTML file? So I can download it and have a look, thanks.

Comment: Ahh, I see... You'll have to move the HTML where you import your script to the bottom of your body tag, here's a with the new HTML pastebin: http://pastebin.com/EdkR2Gb7

Comment: Oh, thanks, but I don't get it... Why is that? And can you also tell me, why in JS you used '$' ? I'm not sure what that means '$'..

Comment: We put the script at the end of the body to make sure that all the in the body has loaded before we load the Javascript, otherwise the Javascript looks for HTML tags that don't exist. And the $'s are a part of JQuery, it's a really quick way of selecting a element, for example $("body") would select the body, $(".main") would select the tag(s) with the class="main" and $("#main") would select the tag(s) with the id="main"

Answer (score 1):

For the first form the problem with your code is that you always look only at the first select, the one with id="choose1". So neke variable will always contain the value choosen in the first select.

Also pay attention that you have the id="choose2" three times in the same page. The id uniquely identifies a HTML element so there shouldn't be 2 different elements with the same id in the same page.

I modified your code to work for the first form. This is not the most elegant solution. I only wanted to better show you what the problem is:

```
<body onload="startTime()">
<p>Temparature</p>
<br />
<form>
    <input id="c" name="c" onkeyup="input1()">
    <select id="chose1">
        <option></option>
        <option value="C">Celzija</option>
        <option value="F">Farenhait</option>
    </select>
    <br />equals
    <br />
    <input id="f" name="f" onkeyup="input2()">
    <select id="chose2">
        <option></option>
        <option value="C">Celzija</option>
        <option value="F">Farenhait</option>
    </select>
</form>
<div id="txt"></div>
```

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function input1()
{
    neke=document.getElementById("chose1").value;

    if(neke=="C")
    {
        fahr=document.getElementById("c").value * 9 / 5 + 32;
        document.getElementById("f").value=Math.round(fahr);
    }else   
    {
        cels=(document.getElementById("f").value -32) * 5 / 9;
        document.getElementById("c").value=Math.round(cels);
    }
}

function input2() {
    neke=document.getElementById("chose2").value;

    if(neke=="C")
    {
        fahr=document.getElementById("c").value * 9 / 5 + 32;
        document.getElementById("f").value=Math.round(fahr);
    }else   
    {
        cels=(document.getElementById("f").value -32) * 5 / 9;
        document.getElementById("c").value=Math.round(cels);
    }

}

function startTime()
{
    var today=new Date();
    var h=today.getHours();
    var m=today.getMinutes();
    var s=today.getSeconds();

    m=checkTime(m);
    s=checkTime(s);
    document.getElementById('txt').innerHTML=h+":"+m+":"+s;
    t=setTimeout('startTime()',500);
}
function checkTime(i)
{
if (i<10)
{
    i="0" + i;
}
    return i;
}
</script>
```